# Answer post deleted when user has trouble logging in

Tags: bug, status-completed, draft

I answered a question, and then Super User asked me to log in.

There was trouble logging in. First, I used http instead of https in my OpenID (which is my fault I suppose).  After correcting this there was a protocol error with Super User trying to talk to my OpenID provider launchpad.net reported back by Super User -- I was never asked for a password.  On the third try I finally got a request to supply a credential.

The browser window was never closed in this sequence of events, which took maybe 5 minutes.  The answer I had written to someone's question, which was kind of long, did not appear once I logged in.  I used the browser back key and got back to the page with the question, but my answer was not there either.

I would suppose the software could store an unauthenticated posting in a temporary area, and set a reminder somehow (cookie?) indicating a lookup index of some kind which is then sent from the user's browser when the user actually does log back in.  These temps could be kept for at least a few hours or so before being deleted (in case someone answered a post and had to run off to a meeting before figuring out why login failed). If so then was it the bad auth that trashed the post? That seems rather sudden. To avoid sounding like an idiot, I won't speculate further.

While I suppose I will try to remember to log in first from now on and then post, it would be nice if the system was a little friendlier when there are login difficulties, because the rest of the system here so far seems very well thought out.

Answer (score 2):

We now save drafts of answers, so this shouldn't happen again.